Вставка записи в таблицу с циклом 3 через 3
Есть необходимость вставить запись в цикле 3/3 в поле Employee за определенный месяц
где первый день месяца начинается с Михаила, а через 3 дня в поле Employee вставляется Ирина, затем через 3 дня снова Михаил и так до конца месяца.
Необходимое поле для изменение я за комментировал
Вот, что есть:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Nums
CREATE TABLE dbo.Nums(DataAdd date
                    ,WeekDayName VARCHAR(15)
                    ,Employee VARCHAR(8)
                    ,Salary INT
);

DECLARE @StartDate date = '2024-05-01'
    ,@EndDate date = '2024-06-01'
    ,@Employee1 VARCHAR(6) = 'Михаил'
    ,@Employee2 VARCHAR(5) = 'Ирина'


WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Nums (DataAdd, WeekDayName, Employee, Salary)
        SELECT [DateAdd] = @StartDate
        ,WeekDayName = DATENAME(dw, @StartDate)
        ,/* Employee = CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(DD, @StartDate) % DAY(@StartDate ) = 31 THEN 'Михаил'
                    ELSE 'Ирина'
                    END*/
        ,Salary = CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 1 THEN  5000 -- в понедельник ставка увеличена
                    ELSE 4000
                    END
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DD, +1, @StartDate) 
END

SELECT * FROM Nums       -- вызов
